# Union two select statements with NOT IN - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two select statements and i need to output 1st select records and the other should receive the records that not output by select 1. 2nd select should not contain the data of select 1. here is my code

```
select b.tcl_tcserno, b.tcl_clmcode, b.tcl_clname, c.prd_desc, e.eqt_desc,
         b.tcl_conamount, b.tcl_intrate, f.numirp_minrate, f.dblirp_intrate,
         b.tcl_prdcode, e.eqt_type
    FROM leaseinfo.trn_ira_intreductapproval a,
         leaseinfo.tbltrialcalculation b,
         corpinfo.tblproduct c,
         leaseinfo.tbltrialequipment d,
         leaseinfo.tblequipmenttype e,
         leaseinfo.ref_irp_inerestratepara f
   WHERE a.numira_tcserno = b.tcl_tcserno
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = c.prd_code
     AND b.tcl_tcserno = d.teq_tcserno
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = e.eqt_prdcode
     AND d.teq_eqttype = e.eqt_type
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = f.strirp_productcode
     AND d.teq_eqttype = f.strirp_eqpttype
     AND a.strira_status = 'E'
     AND (f.numirp_minrate - b.tcl_intrate)<
              (SELECT g.intds_uplim
                       FROM glinfo.ref_tblintratefordesignation g
                      WHERE g.intds_designation IN (
                                        SELECT s.str_off_type
                                        FROM dpg.inf_responsible_maildetails s
                                        WHERE s.str_user_code = '10020336'))
     and  (b.tcl_prdcode='LE' OR b.tcl_prdcode='UV' OR b.tcl_prdcode='HP')
      and (e.EQT_TYPE='2' OR e.EQT_TYPE='9' OR e.EQT_TYPE='15' OR e.EQT_TYPE='17' OR e.EQT_TYPE='21' OR e.EQT_TYPE='23' OR e.EQT_TYPE='25' OR e.EQT_TYPE='28' OR e.EQT_TYPE='30')
ORDER BY b.tcl_tcserno



union all



SELECT   b.tcl_tcserno, b.tcl_clmcode, b.tcl_clname, c.prd_desc, e.eqt_desc,
         b.tcl_conamount, b.tcl_intrate, f.numirp_minrate, f.dblirp_intrate,
         b.tcl_prdcode, e.eqt_type
    FROM leaseinfo.trn_ira_intreductapproval a,
         leaseinfo.tbltrialcalculation b,
         corpinfo.tblproduct c,
         leaseinfo.tbltrialequipment d,
         leaseinfo.tblequipmenttype e,
         leaseinfo.ref_irp_inerestratepara f
   WHERE a.numira_tcserno = b.tcl_tcserno
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = c.prd_code
     AND b.tcl_tcserno = d.teq_tcserno
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = e.eqt_prdcode
     AND d.teq_eqttype = e.eqt_type
     AND b.tcl_prdcode = f.strirp_productcode
     AND d.teq_eqttype = f.strirp_eqpttype
     AND a.strira_status = 'E'
ORDER BY b.tcl_tcserno
```

i think not in will work with this. but i don't have an idea to do with it. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do job using set notation.  Assumes same columns in both queries to work

```
With dat1 as (....),
     Dat2 as (....) 
Select * from dat1 Union all 
 (
  Select * from dat2 except select * from dat1
 )
```